# Problem with codeI need to add a function to my code so that when uploading a post to the site

Tags: node.js

I need to add a function to my code so that when uploading a post to the site, the date of creation of the post is uploaded to the mongodb collection and then displays this date in the post. how do I do this?

I tried many different ways, but nothing worked out, because I'm not good at nodejs and working with servers yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.